# TestNG - How to get current class name from BeforeClass

Tags: java, testng

TestNG - How to get current class name from BeforeClass.

I have class A with extends class B

```
class B {
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        /* Need test class name 'A' */
    }
}
class A extends B {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

In BeforeClass I have tried the only two parameters which inject: ITestContext and XmlTest.
However, no luck in determining how to get the class name from either.

Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following should do the trick:

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    String className = this.getClass().getName();
}
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I wasn't clear.
Both classes live in different class files.

Class A extends Class B.

...and want to avoid passing the class name through a constructor.

Comment: You don't need to, getClass() is a polymorphic call. At least try it before criticizing a valid answer.

Comment: My apologies for not trying it out ....i would of never guess and yet so trivial a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Really? @BeforeClass should be static.

Answer (score 2):

How about `getClass()`?

(a few more characters to keep SO happy)